# AWS Route 53 domain to ec2 not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have an ec2 instance setup with an elastic ip and a security group that allows http from any ip. I created an "a record" for www.thebitterbirds.com to map to my elastic ip, but I cannot connect. If I just try and access the elastic ip in the browser or the public domain name that AWS gave me, it works. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. [image]

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try for DNS lookup first, this will show all the DNS settings if those are reflected as you want. if not you are missing some thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [WhoIs](http://whois.domaintools.com/thebitterbirds.com) data for your domain, you will notice this strange line:

```
Domain Status: clientHold https://icann.org/epp#clientHold
```

Follow that [ICANN](https://icann.org/epp#clientHold) url and you will see the discription of this status:

> Client Status Codes are Set by Your Domain's Registrar:
>
> clientHold: This status code tells your domain's registry to not
>   activate your domain in the DNS and as a consequence, it will not
>   resolve. It is an uncommon status that is usually enacted during legal
>   disputes, non-payment, or when your domain is subject to deletion.

And the suggested way to resolve it:

> Often, this status indicates an issue with your domain that needs
>   resolution. If so, you should contact your registrar to resolve the
>   issue. If your domain does not have any issues, but you need it to
>   resolve, you must first contact your registrar and request that they
>   remove this status code.